# PHP form security - preventing resubmission of email

Tags: php, forms, email, confirm

How much more secure is adding a meta redirect to my php contact form to prevent spammers from blasting emails from my website's contact forms?

One php form will handle the email and send it, then I make it load another page for the confirmation instead of the form that handled the email being the confirmation page. I'm trying to prevent form resubmission on refresh, regardless if my reCaptcha was filled out, which is what was happening...

This is the code I am using to redirect. Using this method, if a person hits BACK on the browser, it will load the page with the form, not the page that sent the mail, which is what I wanted as well. Will this redirect and a reCatpcha on all forms cut down on spam is what I'm asking.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=myconfirmationpage.php"; />
```

Comment: Won't help the slightest bit. These spambots are automated - it's not someone sitting there manually filling out your form.

Comment: If you require a captcha on the first form, and only allow the other forms to be completed if that first was successfully completed, that should solve your issue against spam without being "in the way" of the user. If you just want one email per submission, store it in a database - but spam-bots tend to never use the same email, they're mostly random.

Comment: See Post Redirect Get Pattern (PRG). Its for prevent double send form with F5 reload and also problem with BACK button.